# canLoad não funciona com BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular

O serviço `AuthenticationManager` possui o seguinte código:

```
private loggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

constructor(
     private http: ApplicationHttpClient, 
     private router: Router, private a: HttpClient) 
{
    this.loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
}

isLoggedIn():Observable<boolean> {
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
}

initSession():void {
   this.getUserSession().subscribe(
     response => {
       this.loggedIn.next(true);
     }
   );
}

getUserSession():Observable<any> {
    return this.a.get('http://localhost/api/v1/usersession', {});
}
```

O método `initSession` é chamado pelo `app.component.ts` para consultar a API e obter a sessão do utilizador.

A rota possui o `canLoad` configurado:

```
//...
canLoad: [AccessManagerGuard]
//...
```

O `AccessManagerGuard` possui o seguinte código:

```
canLoad(route: Route): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
    return this.AuthenticationManager.isLoggedIn()
      .map((isLoggedIn: boolean) => {
         if (!isLoggedIn)
           return false;
         return true;
      });
}
```

Repare que o `canLoad` executa o `isLoggedIn` que por sua vez retorna um `Observable`.

```
isLoggedIn():Observable<boolean> {
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
}
```

Dessa forma o `canLoad` não funciona, uma vez que a variável `loggedIn` é iniciada com o valor `false`.

Percebo que o método `isLoggedIn` devolve de imediato o valor `false` porém preciso que aguarde o resultado do método `getUserSession`.

**Como faço para que o método `isLoggedIn` aguarde a resposta do método `getUserSession`?**

Answer (score 0):

A solução foi trocar o `BehaviorSubject` pelo `AsyncSubject` no serviço `AuthenticationManagerService`:

```
private loggedIn: AsyncSubject<boolean> = new AsyncSubject();
//...
isLoggedIn():Observable<boolean> {
    return this.loggedIn;
}

initSession():void {
    this.getUserSession().subscribe(
        response => {
            this.loggedIn.next(true);
            this.loggedIn.complete();
        }
    );
}
//...
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja a imagem acima, o último evento só irá ser emitido após o `complete`, sendo assim é possível criar um evento com o `next` e o valor desejado, que no meu caso só poderia ser emitido após a conclusão do GET REQUEST.

Fonte: https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/creating-an-observable-with-angular-part-ii-the-4-different-types-3d8fd2835850